# Why am I getting this error when trying to run a newly created web application?

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications

I was trying to run this new web application that I had just created but I end up getting this error:

```
ant -f "D:\\University All Sync Drive\\Data Structures & Specialist Programming CS5003\\ShoppingCart" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true "-Dbrowser.context=D:\\University All Sync Drive\\Data Structures & Specialist Programming CS5003\\ShoppingCart" run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at D:\University All Sync Drive\Data Structures & Specialist Programming CS5003\ShoppingCart\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
D:\University All Sync Drive\Data Structures & Specialist Programming CS5003\ShoppingCart\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do what it tells you, ***"See the server log for details"***, so you can see *why* it failed, and then maybe figure out what to fix?

Comment: @Andreas And where can I find the server log?

Comment: @Andreas Actually nevermind, found it.

Comment: @Andreas I am looking at the server log but I don't understand it.

Comment: You needed help understanding the `ant` output, so you posted a question here asking about it. Why don't you apply the same logic to the problem of understanding the server log, i.e. post it here to get help? I'd suggest you **edit** this question and add (the relevant part of) the server log.

Comment: @It's okay. I figured out that I would only get the error if I had the project saved on my google drive but I am not sure why that is.